# How to install earlier versions of xcproj

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I reinstalled xcproj with

```
brew uninstall xcproj
brew install xcproj
```

This installed the current version (0.2.1) but I need the version 0.1 (compatibility issues with my current project). I tried the methods described in [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) but couldn't find how to install earlier versions of xcproj. How can I install version 0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by building and installing xcproj manually

```
brew uninstall xcproj
git clone https://github.com/0xced/xcproj.git
git checkout 0.1.2
xcodebuild install DSTROOT=/
```